# Moq SetupProperty not working

Tags: moq

Can someone tell me whey the following code blows when the moq.SetupProperty fails in the code below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SimulatorService_Returns_HighScores()
{
    IScoreService scoreService = new ScoreService(MockScoreRepository.GetMockScoreRepository());
    Assert.IsNotNull(scoreService);
    var highScores = scoreService.GetHighScores();
    Assert.IsTrue(highScores.Count > 0);
}


public static class MockScoreRepository
{

    public static ScoreEntry GetMockScoreEntry(int seed)
    {
        var moq = new Mock<ScoreEntry>();

        moq.SetupProperty(s => s.UserID, seed);
        moq.SetupProperty(s => s.Score, 10 * seed);
        moq.SetupProperty(s => s.EntryDate, DateTime.Now);

        return moq.Object;
    }

    public static IScoreRepository GetMockScoreRepository()
    {
        var scores = new List<ScoreEntry>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            scores.Add(GetMockScoreEntry(i));
        }

        var repository = new Mock<IScoreRepository>();
        repository.Setup(r => r.GetScores()).Returns(scores.AsQueryable());

        return repository.Object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exception you're getting?

Comment: Tried to reproduce but could not. Can you post the error and line that blows? Also declarations of relevant classes and interfaces.

Comment: The line `Assert.IsNotNull(scoreService);` is pointless- constructors return a reference to an instance or throw an exception, it is not possible for a constructor to somehow return a null reference. See the C# spec. §7.6.10.1 Object creation expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd check is to make sure that the properties of ScoreEntry that you're setting have accessible setters. In other words, make sure your setters have public access or that you at least have a setter for each property you're attempting to set through moq.